# Tableau + R: Cholmod error 'invalid rset'

Tags: r, tableau-api, recommendation-engine

I am building a recommender system in Tableau. Code below, arg values are being passed as column vectors.

```
library(reshape2);
library(recommenderlab);
curUser = .arg1;
df <- data.frame(username=.arg1, workbook=.arg2, value=.arg3);
recMatrix <- as(as.matrix(acast(df,username ~ workbook)), "realRatingMatrix");
recModel <- Recommender(recMatrix[1:nrow(recMatrix)], method = "UBCF");
rec <- predict(recModel, recMatrix[rownames(recMatrix) == curUser,], n=10);
recList <- as(rec, "list");
paste(recList[1][[1]], collapse = ",");
```

When I run this as as Rscript outside of Tableau, it works perfectly. When I try running it in Tableau, it works perfectly till the predict statement. I am encountering the following error

> Error in subCsp_ij(x, i, j, drop = drop) : Cholmod error 'invalid
>   rset' at file ../MatrixOps/cholmod_submatrix.c, line 209

I dont know what to make of this and how to go about debugging this issue! Any help would be amazing!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cholmod_submatrix.c` parses the rownames of the matrix as integers while the matrix that is constructed has rownames as Strings. Changing it to integers got it working!